# JSON php parse

Tags: php

Формирую json с помощью средств java следующего вида и отправляю его на сервер, сохраняют в базу. На сервере там пхп апи. Каким образом распарсить этот json и превратить его в что-то сносное, чем можно будет пользоваться. Мне нужно создать функцию которая возвращает true или false входные параметры функции: массив 1, массив 2. Массивы состоят из координат. Это координаты маршрута. нужно определить входит ли массив 1 в массив 2 или пересекается, если одно из этих условий выполняется, то возвращаю true, иначе false

раньше с пхп не работал, не изучал. Пришлось сейчас пользоваться. пхп хороший язык, но сейчас нет особо времени изучать его полностью.

Больше чем помощь с пхп, мне нужна помощь с этим алгоритмом сравнения двух массивов вида a[долгота, широта]. Дело в том, что этот маршрут получаю с помощью геокодера гугл. Но если тупо сравнивать эти значения то может быть ситуация, что маршруты будут совпадать, но точки будут не равны. Можно конечно округлить до какого-то знака и сравнивать, но как-то это не то. Суть в том, что есть определенный заданный пользователем маршрут, есть в базе данных например 10 маршрутов. И нужно определить какой из маршрутов совпадает или пересекается с заданным маршрутом.

```
[{"lon":"30.45401","lat":"50.4297"},{"lon":"30.45391","lat":"50.42984"},{"lon":"30.45366","lat":"50.4299"},{"lon":"30.45127","lat":"50.43063"},{"lon":"30.44758","lat":"50.43171"},{"lon":"30.44758","lat":"50.43171"},{"lon":"30.44847","lat":"50.43297"},{"lon":"30.44865","lat":"50.43323"},{"lon":"30.45063","lat":"50.43593"},{"lon":"30.45072","lat":"50.43606"},{"lon":"30.45097","lat":"50.4364"},{"lon":"30.45174","lat":"50.4375"}]
```

вот так мне кажется нужно перевести в массив

```
$ar=json_decode($json);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то вот решение:

```
<?php
// Пользовательский маршрут
$user_route_json = '['
    . '{"lon":"30.45401","lat":"50.4297"},{"lon":"30.45391","lat":"50.42984"},'  //1
    . '{"lon":"30.45366","lat":"50.4299"},{"lon":"30.45127","lat":"50.43063"},'  //2
    . '{"lon":"30.44758","lat":"50.43171"},{"lon":"30.44758","lat":"50.43171"},' //3
    . '{"lon":"30.44847","lat":"50.43297"},{"lon":"30.44865","lat":"50.43323"},' //4
    . '{"lon":"30.45063","lat":"50.43593"},{"lon":"30.45072","lat":"50.43606"},' //5
    . '{"lon":"30.45097","lat":"50.4364"},{"lon":"30.45174","lat":"50.4375"}'    //6
    . ']';

// Предустановленные маршруты
// Чтобы было проще сравнивать, у одинаковых элементов - одинаковые комментарии

$route_pack_json = array(
    // Предустановленный маршрут идентичен пользовательскому | TRUE
    '['
    . '{"lon":"30.45401","lat":"50.4297"},{"lon":"30.45391","lat":"50.42984"},'  //1
    . '{"lon":"30.45366","lat":"50.4299"},{"lon":"30.45127","lat":"50.43063"},'  //2
    . '{"lon":"30.44758","lat":"50.43171"},{"lon":"30.44758","lat":"50.43171"},' //3
    . '{"lon":"30.44847","lat":"50.43297"},{"lon":"30.44865","lat":"50.43323"},' //4
    . '{"lon":"30.45063","lat":"50.43593"},{"lon":"30.45072","lat":"50.43606"},' //5
    . '{"lon":"30.45097","lat":"50.4364"},{"lon":"30.45174","lat":"50.4375"}'    //6
    . ']',

    // Предустановленный маршрут включает ВСЕ точки пользовательского | TRUE
    '['
    . '{"lon":"30.45455","lat":"50.4211"},{"lon":"30.45388","lat":"50.42981"},'
    . '{"lon":"30.45445","lat":"50.4213"},{"lon":"30.45389","lat":"50.42982"},'
    . '{"lon":"30.45401","lat":"50.4297"},{"lon":"30.45391","lat":"50.42984"},'  //1
    . '{"lon":"30.45366","lat":"50.4299"},{"lon":"30.45127","lat":"50.43063"},'  //2
    . '{"lon":"30.44758","lat":"50.43171"},{"lon":"30.44758","lat":"50.43171"},' //3
    . '{"lon":"30.44847","lat":"50.43297"},{"lon":"30.44865","lat":"50.43323"},' //4
    . '{"lon":"30.45063","lat":"50.43593"},{"lon":"30.45072","lat":"50.43606"},' //5
    . '{"lon":"30.45097","lat":"50.4364"},{"lon":"30.45174","lat":"50.4375"}'    //6

    . ']',

    // Предустановленный маршрут включает ЧАСТЬ точек пользовательского | FALSE
    '['
    . '{"lon":"30.45401","lat":"50.4297"},{"lon":"30.45391","lat":"50.42984"},'  //1
    . '{"lon":"30.45366","lat":"50.4299"},{"lon":"30.45127","lat":"50.43063"},'  //2
    . '{"lon":"30.44758","lat":"50.43171"},{"lon":"30.44758","lat":"50.43171"},' //3
    . '{"lon":"30.44847","lat":"50.43297"},{"lon":"30.44865","lat":"50.43323"}'  //4
    . ']',

    // Предустановленный маршрут НЕ СОДЕРЖИТ точек пользовательского | FALSE
    '['
    . '{"lon":"30.45455","lat":"50.4211"},{"lon":"30.45388","lat":"50.42981"},'
    . '{"lon":"30.45445","lat":"50.4213"},{"lon":"30.45389","lat":"50.42982"}'
    . ']'
);

// Конвертируем пользовательские данные из JSON в массив
$user_route = json_decode($user_route_json, TRUE);

// Конвертируем предустановленные данные из JSON в массив
$route_pack = array();
foreach ($route_pack_json as $route_json) {
    $route_pack[] = json_decode($route_json, TRUE);
}

function compare_routes($route, $user_route)
{
    // Работаем только с массивами
    if (!is_array($user_route) || !is_array($route)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Сколько точек из пользовательского маршрута ОТСУТСТВУЕТ в предустановленном
    $differences = count(array_diff_assoc($user_route, $route));

    if ($differences === 0) {
        // Все точки пользовательского маршрута есть в предустановленном
        // Это значит, что маршруты или идентичны,
        // Или предустановленный содержит пользовательский целиком
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Сравниваем каждый маршрут из списка предустановленных с пользовательским
foreach ($route_pack as $route) {
    var_dump(compare_routes($route, $user_route));
}

// Результат для нашего примера: bool(true) bool(true) bool(false) bool(false)
// Это соответствует действительности
```

Comment: очень благодарю, сейчас попробую

Comment: Я обновил ответ, перепутал местами аргументы функции, когда набирал ответ...

Comment: один маленький вопрос: когда я из базы получаю эти координаты, у меня в базе json находится в формате text. Для php это не критично если json будет как text?

$user_route_json=mysql_query("SELECT coord FROM coords WHERE email='$email'");
$user_route = json_decode($user_route_json, TRUE);
$route_pack_json = mysql_query("SELECT coord FROM coords");
  
$route_pack = array();
foreach ($route_pack_json as $route_json) {
$route_pack[] = json_decode($route_json, TRUE);
}
так нормально? мне кажется что пхп все считает за строку или это не так?

Comment: теперь самый важный момент- есть другая таблица состоящая из пользователей и у каждого есть поле: емаил. Таблица с координатами тоже имеет поле емаил. Надо каким-то образом сделать связь между этими таблицами. Всмысле сделать что-то наподобие foreach ($route_pack as $route) {
    if(compare_routes($route, $user_route));
 ar_mail[]= какаятоструктура.email;
}